Loop and grouping with Time Series in R
I am creating a loop to calculate a proxy called "effective tick" on a panel dataset where the rows represent dates and the columns represent companies. The structure of the dataset is as follows:
> str(data_effective1)
'data.frame':   3132 obs. of  507 variables:
 $ data                               : Date, format: "2012-11-23" "2012-11-26" ...
 $ AMAZON.COM                         : num  12 12.2 12.2 12.4 12.6 ...
 $ ABBOTT LABORATORIES                : num  30.8 30.8 30.7 30.9 31.1 ...
 $ AES                                : num  10.1 10.2 10.2 10.4 10.4 ...

> dput(head(data_effective1))
data_effective1 <-
  structure(list(
    data = structure(c(15667, 15670, 15671, 15672, 15673, 15674), class = "Date"), 
    `ABBOTT LABORATORIES` = c(30.8472, 30.7945, 30.651, 30.895, 31.139, 31.1008), 
    `ALLSTATE ORD SHS` = c(40.74, 40.45, 40.42, 40.63, 40.64, 40.48)
  )) |> as.data.frame()

Currently, I have created a loop to calculate the effective tick for each column, and this is the result:

effective_tick<-numeric(ncol(data_effective1)-1)

for (i in 2 : (ncol(data_effective1))) {
   cents<-data_effective1[,2]-floor(data_effective1[,2])
   cents<-round(cents*100)
#cluster
cluster <- ifelse(cents %% 100 == 0, 1.00, # Dollar
             ifelse(cents %% 25 == 0, 0.25, # Quarter
             ifelse(cents %% 10 == 0, 0.10, # Dime
             ifelse(cents %% 5 == 0, 0.05,  # Nickel
                    0.01))))#penny
N_j <- table(cluster)
F_j <- N_j / sum(N_j) 

# Step 4: Calcolare le probabilità non vincolate
#inizializzazione
U_j <- numeric(length(F_j))
names(U_j) <- names(F_j)


#per il primo cluster
U_j[1] <- 2 * F_j[1]
#per gli altri

if (length(U_j) > 1) {
    for (j in 2:(length(U_j) - 1)) {
        U_j[j] <- 2 * F_j[j] - F_j[j - 1]
    }
    U_j[length(U_j)] <- F_j[length(U_j)] - F_j[length(U_j) - 1]
}

# Step 5: Vincolare le probabilità
#inizializzazione
g_j <- numeric(length(U_j))
names(g_j) <- names(U_j)


  g_j[1] <- pmin(pmax(U_j[1], 0), 1)
if(length(g_j) > 1) {
  for (j in 2:length(U_j)) {
    g_j[j] <- pmin(pmax(U_j[j], 0), 1 - sum(g_j[1:(j - 1)]))
  }
}


sum(g_j)
# Step 6: Determinare lo spread effettivo per ciascun cluster
s_j <- as.numeric(names(F_j))

# Step 7: Calcolare il prezzo medio
mean_price <- mean(data_effective1[,i])

# Step 8: Calcolare l'Effective Tick
effective_tick[i]<- sum(g_j * s_j) / mean_price
}

The problem now is that I need to iterate this loop for each month, and I don’t know how to do it. I’ve tried various methods, but so far, I haven’t succeeded. My ideas are:

Nest a loop inside this one that iterates by month.
Create a function that performs what the first loop does and then apply it, grouping by month.

One of the issues is that I have a lot of NAs, but I can’t remove them because this dataset represents the S&P 500, with companies entering and exiting the index. Removing the NAs would mean losing rows and creating gaps in the data.
Does anyone have ideas? I’m a bit stuck.

Write your code as a function and call it for each group of month. The months are determined with format, extracting only the year/month combination from the date column.
In the code below I have changed the input argument name from data_effective1 to X. And the function returns a data frame.
I include two ways of calling it for each sub-df, one with byand the other with split/lapply.
calc_tick <- function(X) { 
  effective_tick <- numeric(ncol(X) - 1)

  for (i in 2:(ncol(X))) {
    cents <- X[,2] - floor(X[,2])
    cents <- round(cents*100)
    #cluster
    cluster <- ifelse(cents %% 100 == 0, 1.00,                    # Dollar
                      ifelse(cents %% 25 == 0, 0.25,              # Quarter
                             ifelse(cents %% 10 == 0, 0.10,       # Dime
                                    ifelse(cents %% 5 == 0, 0.05, # Nickel
                                           0.01))))               # penny
    N_j <- table(cluster)
    F_j <- N_j / sum(N_j) 

    # Step 4: Calcolare le probabilità non vincolate
    #inizializzazione
    U_j <- numeric(length(F_j))
    names(U_j) <- names(F_j)

    #per il primo cluster
    U_j[1] <- 2 * F_j[1]
    #per gli altri

    if (length(U_j) > 1) {
      for (j in 2:(length(U_j) - 1)) {
        U_j[j] <- 2 * F_j[j] - F_j[j - 1]
      }
      U_j[length(U_j)] <- F_j[length(U_j)] - F_j[length(U_j) - 1]
    }

    # Step 5: Vincolare le probabilità
    #inizializzazione
    g_j <- numeric(length(U_j))
    names(g_j) <- names(U_j)

    g_j[1] <- pmin(pmax(U_j[1], 0), 1)
    if(length(g_j) > 1) {
      for (j in 2:length(U_j)) {
        g_j[j] <- pmin(pmax(U_j[j], 0), 1 - sum(g_j[1:(j - 1)]))
      }
    }

    # sum(g_j)
    # Step 6: Determinare lo spread effettivo per ciascun cluster
    s_j <- as.numeric(names(F_j))
    
    # Step 7: Calcolare il prezzo medio
    mean_price <- mean(data_effective1[,i])
    
    # Step 8: Calcolare l'Effective Tick
    effective_tick[i - 1L]<- sum(g_j * s_j) / mean_price
  }
  effective_tick |> t() |> as.data.frame() |> setNames(names(X)[-1L])
}

Month <- format(data_effective1$data, "%Y-%m")

by(data_effective1, Month, calc_tick) |> 
  data.table::rbindlist(idcol = TRUE) |>
  as.data.frame()
#>       .id ABBOTT.LABORATORIES ALLSTATE.ORD.SHS
#> 1 2012-11        0.0003235766     0.0002465483

split(data_effective1, Month) |>
  lapply(calc_tick) |> 
  data.table::rbindlist(idcol = TRUE) |>
  as.data.frame()
#>       .id ABBOTT.LABORATORIES ALLSTATE.ORD.SHS
#> 1 2012-11        0.0003235766     0.0002465483

Created on 2024-11-30 with reprex v2.1.1

Data
data_effective1 <-
  structure(list(
    data = structure(c(15667, 15670, 15671, 15672, 15673, 15674), class = "Date"), 
    `ABBOTT LABORATORIES` = c(30.8472, 30.7945, 30.651, 30.895, 31.139, 31.1008), 
    `ALLSTATE ORD SHS` = c(40.74, 40.45, 40.42, 40.63, 40.64, 40.48)
  )) |> as.data.frame()


TY! I implemented something similar using a double loop, but your function is even better. I just made a small adjustment to handle cases where there are fewer than three clusters in the monthly groups, which was causing some issues.However, I noticed a slight difference between the results from my loop and your function. In your function, I get some zeros (which make sense) that I don’t get with mine, so I’m trying to figure out why. If you’d like to take a look, I can share the link to the repository with you.  https://github.com/GiulioSurya/RAship---Liquidity-Risk-Premium/tree/main
